# Liferay - Not able to attach a Document Library item to JournalArticle in Remote portal

Tags: java, liferay

I have been trying to create a copy of my local JournalArticle in a remote portal. But even though I provide the correct URL in `content` section of article, it does not appear in the portal. I have been stuck on this issue for a couple of days already.

I create the article as follows.

```
JournalArticleSoap journalArticleSoap = journalSoap.addArticle(
    remoteGroupId,
    article.getFolderId(),
    article.getClassNameId(),
    article.getClassPK(),
    "",
    true,
    LocalizationUtil.getAvailableLanguageIds(article.getTitle()),
    titleMapValues.toArray(new String[titleMapValues.size()]),
    LocalizationUtil.getAvailableLanguageIds(article.getDescription()),
    descriptionMapValues.toArray(new String[descriptionMapValues.size()]),
    content,
    article.getType(),
    article.getStructureId(),
    newRemoteTemplate.getTemplateKey(),
    article.getLayoutUuid(),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.HOUR),
    displayDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, //expirationDate
    article.getExpirationDate() == null,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    true,
    article.isIndexable(),
    article.getUrlTitle(),
    serviceContext);
```

where `journalSoap` is the JournalArticleServiceSoap of the remote portal and `article` is the local JournalArticle.

The content is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
    <dynamic-element name="Text2001" type="text" index-type="keyword" index="0">
        <dynamic-content language-id="en_US"><![CDATA[Desert image]]></dynamic-content>
    </dynamic-element>
    <dynamic-element name="Documents_and_Media2051" type="document_library" index-type="keyword" index="0">
        <dynamic-content language-id="en_US"><![CDATA[/documents/20101/20201/Photo1]]></dynamic-content>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

In the above url (`/documents/20101/20201/Photo1`), 20101 is the Global group ID of the remote portal, 20201 is the id of the folder in the remote document library where Photo1 is created. When I go to `http://host:port/documents/20101/20201/Photo1`, I get the file downloaded. But still, the article in the remote portal looks like below.

[image]

As you can see, I am getting the textual dynamic element "Desert image" in the remote article. But I am not getting the dynamic element from the document library into the remote article. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was removing the uuid and creation timestamp from the url.

When I replaced `/documents/20101/20201/Photo1` with `/documents/20101/20201/Photo1/uuid?t=timestamp` it started working. Here uuid is the uuid and timestamp is the creation time (long type) of the file Photo1.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a structured (contains only D&M uploader field) article from frontend and check that XML in DB you'll find the difference what exactly going wrong.